# Separate clock-in and clock-out for each date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple table which records people clocking-in and clocking out like so.

```
Id     | EmployeeNumber | InOutDateTime
-----------------------------------------------------
1      | 505            | 2020-03-24 08:32:42:000
2      | 506            | 2020-03-24 08:35:47:000
3      | 507            | 2020-03-24 08:46:12:000
4      | 505            | 2020-03-24 16:59:00:000
5      | 506            | 2020-03-24 17:05:00:000
6      | 508            | 2020-03-24 17:46:12:000
```

I want to separate clock-in and clock-out for each date.

So, based on my table above, I want to get the following results:

```
EmployeeNumber | InDateTime               | OutDateTime
----------------------------------------------------------------------
505            | 2020-03-24 08:32:42:000  | 2020-03-24 16:59:00:000
506            | 2020-03-24 08:35:47:000  | 2020-03-24 17:05:00:000
507            | 2020-03-24 08:46:12:000  | null
508            | null                     | 2020-03-24 17:46:12:000
```

I have been playing with subquery and grouping but not getting it. Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you decide when `InOutDateTime` is `In` or `Out` for a single `EmployeeNumber` input?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following statement, but the important question is how do you decide when `InOutDateTime` is `In` or `Out` for a single `EmployeeNumber` input:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Id int,
   EmployeeNumber int,
   InOutDateTime datetime
)
INSERT INTO Data (Id, EmployeeNumber, InOutDateTime)
VALUES
   (1, 505, '2020-03-24T08:32:42'),
   (2, 506, '2020-03-24T08:35:47'),
   (3, 507, '2020-03-24T08:46:12'),
   (4, 505, '2020-03-24T16:59:00'),
   (5, 506, '2020-03-24T17:05:00'),
   (6, 508, '2020-03-24T17:46:12')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   EmployeeNumber, 
   MIN(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, InOutDateTime) <= 12 THEN InOutDateTime END) AS InDateTime,
   MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, InOutDateTime) > 12 THEN InOutDateTime END) AS OutDateTime
FROM Data
GROUP BY EmployeeNumber, CONVERT(date, InOutDateTime)
ORDER BY EmployeeNumber, CONVERT(date, InOutDateTime)
```

Result:

```
EmployeeNumber  InDateTime              OutDateTime
505             2020-03-24 08:32:42.000 2020-03-24 16:59:00.000
506             2020-03-24 08:35:47.000 2020-03-24 17:05:00.000
507             2020-03-24 08:46:12.000 
508                                     2020-03-24 17:46:12.000
```

Comment: @Mamoxa Does this example provide a solution to your problem?